# Puzzling result for CharacterisicFunction and InverseFourierSequenceTransform

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, fourier-analysis

Observe:

```
cf = CharacteristicFunction[PascalDistribution[1, p], t];
rPDF = InverseFourierSequenceTransform[cf, t, n, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}];

FullSimplify[PDF[PascalDistribution[1, p], n] == rPDF, n >= 1]
FullSimplify[PDF[PascalDistribution[1, p], n] == FourierCoefficient[cf, t, n], n >= 1]
```

> True
>
> True

As expected, the *IFST* of the *CF* is equivalent to the PDF, and also equivalent to the *FC* of the *CF*.

Now,

```
cf = CharacteristicFunction[GeometricDistribution[p], t];
rPDF = InverseFourierSequenceTransform[cf, t, n, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}];

FullSimplify[PDF[GeometricDistribution[p], n] == rPDF, n >= 1]

FullSimplify[PDF[GeometricDistribution[p], n] == FourierCoefficient[cf, t, n],  n >= 1]
```

results in:

[image]

and

> True

The returned expression under simplification using various assumptions returns nonsense, and itself is nonsense (e.g. it contains an assumption implying probability *p* >1 or *p*<0). I also manipulated the `FourierParameters` to no avail.

The example with `GeometricDistribution` returns correct results if the parameter *p* is explicitly specified as some valid probability.

I re-read the appropriate documentation entries to check if my recollection was faulty (I'm quite sure I used this functionality for `GeometricDistribution` before), and strangely the very example is the last entry for the *Properties and Relations*  of `CharacteristicFunction`, where the correct results are shown, but if I re-evaluate the documentation example, I get the same nonsense.

Has something changed in `InverseFourierSequenceTransform` in recent versions (the above is on 9.1, Windows)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does appear something might have been tinkered with, or my recollection / documentation is in error.

```
InverseFourierSequenceTransform[cf, t, -n, FourierParameters -> {1, 1},
   Assumptions -> 0 < p < 1] // PiecewiseExpand
```

properly recovers the *PDF* (*PMF*) for the `GeometricDistribution` case.